# The import javax.servlet and org.hibernate cannot be resolved - Eclipse Kepler on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, hibernate, tomcat

I installed latest version of Eclipse Java EE Kepler version.
And tried to write easy program on Java. But when I make some import statements I catch message:

```
The import xxx cannot be resolved.
```

It doesn't work for - `javax.servlet, org.hibernate, org.springframework, org.junit`.

I don't know why exactly this happen. I'm using 1.7 JDK + tomcat 7. Current OS is Ubuntu 12.04.
I added tomcat 7 to eclipse, and SpringSource Tool Suite for Eclipse Kepler.

***How to solve this trouble?***

Comment: `It works for` or `It does not work for` - typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the other question you need to either to download the jar files manually and add them to the class path, or use a build tool such as maven it will help you download the dependencies you will specify in the `pom.xml` file and add them to the classpath. And more to that you can run build and package in a `war` file for deploying your application into tomcat

Answer (score 2):

java.servlet, org.hibernate, etc. are not part of the JDK. They're external libraries (jars) that must be added to the classpath.

Comment: Right-click on the project, and choose Build Path. Then add the needed jars. You'll have to read the coumentationof the libraries you're using to know all the required jars, or use a dependency management system like gradle or Maven. Frankly, if you don't know how to add jars in a classpath, it's probably way too early for you to use Spring, Hibernate and Tomcat. Learn the basics first.

Answer (score 0):

For hibernate, be sure you added spring-orm in your pom.xml file

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```